# Query to get a output in desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Proc  type  add sub multi div
1       A     1   0    1   1
1       B     2   2    0   1
```

Output should be in the format

```
Proc Aadd Asub Amulti Adiv Badd Bsub Bmulti Bdiv
1     1    0     1      1    2    2   0      1
```

Comment: google pivot sql

Comment: @Programnik I searched for pivot in Google but stil Iam not getting the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach using CTE and Joins.

```sql
declare @table table(Proce  int, type  char(1), addi int, sub int, multi int, div int)
insert into @table values
(1,'A',     1,   0,    1,   1),
(1,'B',     2,   2,    0,   1);

;with cte_a as
(
SELECT proce, max(addi) as Aadd, max(sub) as Asub, max(multi) as Amulti, max(div) as Adiv  
FROM @table where type = 'A'
group by proce
),cte_b as
(
SELECT proce, max(addi) as Badd, max(sub) as Bsub, max(multi) as Bmulti, max(div) as Bdiv  
FROM @table where type = 'B'
group by proce
)
SELECT a.proce,a.aAdd, a.aSub, a.Amulti, a.Adiv,b.BAdd,b.bsub, b.bmulti, b.bdiv
from cte_a as a
join cte_b as b
on a.Proce = b.Proce
```

| proce | aAdd | aSub | Amulti | Adiv | BAdd | bsub | bmulti | bdiv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 4):

A simple conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Select Proc
      ,Aadd  = max( case when type='A' then add   else 0 end)
      ,Asub  = max( case when type='A' then sub   else 0 end)
      ,Amuti = max( case when type='A' then multi else 0 end)
      ,Adiv  = max( case when type='A' then div   else 0 end)
      ,Badd  = max( case when type='B' then add   else 0 end)
      ,Bsub  = max( case when type='B' then sub   else 0 end)
      ,Bmuti = max( case when type='B' then multi else 0 end)
      ,Bdiv  = max( case when type='B' then div   else 0 end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Proc
```

Comment: But it showing null if the data is not present but actually I need 0 instead of null

Comment: @vinothKumar simply add  "ELSE 0"  for example ... THEN sub ELSE 0 END

Comment: @vinothKumar The answer you accepted would show NULL as well